# problema paso de arrays como punteros

Tags: c++

Estaba haciendo un programa de calculo del elemento central de un vector, como parametros tengo que pasar la direccion base de un vector (o sea, que el puntero ya por defecto apunta al primer elemento) y el numero de elementos, mi principal duda es qué diferencia hay entre hacer  `p = &vector;`y hacer solo `p=vector`.

Este es el programa:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int elemento_central (int *array, int elementos );


int main (void){
  int vector[10];
  int central =0;
  int *p;

  vector[0]=50;
  //p = vector;

  p = &vector;
  for (int i=1; i <= 10;i++){
    vector[i]=vector[i-1]+1;
    //(*vector[i])++;
  }


  int b= elemento_central (vector,10);

   cout << " el elemento central es " << central << endl; 

}  

int elemento_central (int *array, int elementos) {
  int izq;

  *array=izq;

  int dch;

  *array + (elementos-1) = dch;

  int mitad = (izq + dch)/2;

  return mitad;
}
```

corregí un par de errores al compilarlo, pero no queria hacer el programa sin tener claros algunos conceptos.

y me sigue saliendo este error en el compilador:

```
pseudocodigop6.cpp: In function ‘int elemento_central(int*, int)’:
pseudocodigop6.cpp:36:26: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   *array + (elementos-1) = dch;
```

Answer (score 3):

La declaración del vector:

```
int vector[10];
```

es, en términos de punteros, equivalente a esta otra:

```
int* vector;
```

Es decir, la variable `vector` es realmente un puntero que apunta a la primera posición del arreglo. Así, `vector[4]` es equivalente a `vector + 4`, es decir, aplica un desplazamiento de 4 posiciones sobre la posición apuntada por `vector` (y es por ello que así accedes al 5º elemento).

Por otro lado, la referencia permite obtener la posición de memoria donde se encuentra una variable:

```
int var;
int* ptr = &var;   // ptr almacena la posición de memoria de var
int** ptr2 = &ptr; // ptr2 almacena la posición de memoria de ptr
```

Así pues, si haces `p = &vector` entonces `p` debería ser un puntero doble, que no es el caso y por ende esa instrucción es errónea. Lo correcto es hacer `p = vector`

Comment: Al que vota negativo: podías al menos indicar en qué no estás conforme. Eso ayudaría a escribir mejores respuestas.